# Trouble starting mysqld on mysql cluster

Tags: mysql

I set a cluster using mysql-cluster-gpl-7.2.12, first it was working fine but suddenly started to fail. I can start the nodes (ndbd) but when I try to start mysqld (API), it shows an error it says "The server quit without PID file (path/dbnode1.pid).

I removed ibdata1 and rebuilt the database using the command `./scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql` to create it again but it doesn't start, moved my.cnf file and it didn't work.

Do you have any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue a couple of times. Fixed it once, still working on the last one.  The one time I got it going I used brute force; I re-installed mysql-cluster (replacing existing files and packages) and since my config and start scripts were in custom directories they were unaffected. A reboot and auto-magically things worked. I think I had had an odd file permissions issue that the re-install fixed.